# How to fetch data from firebase real time database in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have to fetch all children data from firebase real time database? I want to fetch received messages of User2. How to do that? Database example is as given below -

[image]

Comment: where is attached image ?

Comment: I have added but can't see here.

Comment: add it again in edit.

Comment: what you need to fetch from your image ?

Comment: Hey I have edited the ques. Please suggest answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to fetch the children data, try the following:

```
 DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child("User1").child("MSG_TYPE_SENT");

reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
     String msgContent=datas.child("msgContent").getValue().toString();
     String msgType=datas.child("msgType").getValue().toString();
    }
  }
 @Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
 });
```

This will give you the `msgContent` and the `msgType`, to retrieve any data from the database, you need to pass through every node example:-

```
getReference("users").child("User1").child("MSG_TYPE_SENT");
```

Then you can loop inside the ids and retrieve the data.

Comment: Can we use map or any other thing to get children instead of using - getReference("users").child("User1").child("MSG_TYPE_SENT");
this?? because if there are number of children this way may be too lengthy.

Comment: you can add them in one child, `child("User1/MSG_TYPE_SENT")` anyway you should not nest the database alot, it should be flat database

Answer (score 0):

Here you can fetch the User2 Messages Received

```
        DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

        mDatabase.child("User2").child("MSG_TYPE_RECEIVED").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                           for(DataSnapshot spanshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                             String content=snapshot.child("msgContent").getValue(String.class);
                             String type=snapshot.child("msgType").getValue(String.class);

                             //then you can log those values
                             Log.d("Values:",""+content+""+type);

                       }


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

If the message received change at any time (lets say you want to implement the delete option in realtime of the message like whatsapp) `.addValueEventListener` will update your UI in realtime if you have coded to show that the message has been deleted